# R; how to solve an "expired PostgreSQLConnection" error?

Tags: r, postgresql, database-connection

I have a file with R code that builds up several dataframes and next tries to store them into a Postgres database. This ususally fails, the code snippet that fails is below.

```
require ("RPostgreSQL")

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
res <- dbConnect (drv, dbname = db,
           host = "localhost", port = 5432,
           user = "postgres", password = pw)

table_name <- "gemeenten" 
print (c ("adding ", table_name))
if (dbExistsTable (con, table_name)) dbRemoveTable (con, table_name) ### Error!
result <- dbWriteTable (con, table_name, gemeenten)
```

The error I get is:

```
Error in postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) : 
  expired PostgreSQLConnection
```

and the error occurs at the test of `dbExistsTable`. When I call `dbListConnections (PostgreSQL ())` then umber of connections increases by one each time, a call `dbDisconnect (con)` does not decrement this number.

I got this error before when I tried to create the driver from a .Profile file and I could resolve this be removing the `drv` variable and assigning it again. I have succeeded twice in creating this table but I am not able to reconstruct why this happened. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the things I noticed is that I started to get this error when I started sourcing my trials. When starting to source I made a lot of mistakes and I noticed in the Postgres status screen that these connections remained open. I carefully tried to `disConnect` all connections after usage. Using a `tryCatch` block is very useful in this respect. Use the `finally` branch to close the connection, unload the driver and remove their variables. It is not enough when you close connections from Postgres, R still thinks they're open and will refuse any connection attempt after there are 16 connections open. `dbListConnections (PostgreSQL ())` returns a list, `disConnect` all elements of that list.

This did not work at first, I tried to remove package "RPostgreSQL" but that did not work either. I had to manually kill it from the library. As I am a newbie in R as in Postgres I suspect I did something wrong during install. Anyway, remove and reinstall the package. Next restart the Postgres server. After that it worked.

Somewhat paranoid I agree, but after having lost a night of sleep I didn't want to take any chances :-) If someone can pinpoint more precisely the cause of the problem I'll happily choose his answer as the correct one.

Comment: I call `sapply(dbListConnections(drv), dbDisconnect)` at the start of my script as I can't think how to close connections when scripts fail or are hard-terminated.

Comment: That seems a good solution to me, I'll try that the next time I have to do something in R.